# Innodb Error After Master Server Migration

Tags: mysql, innodb, replication, database-migration

I successfully migrated mysql data from one server to another using the 'rsync' technique.

The migrated server was configured as a replication master.

After migration, I get the error message on starting up mysql;

```
140127  8:02:40 [Warning] option 'thread_concurrency': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
140127  8:02:43  InnoDB: Error: page 16683 log sequence number 771 676393429
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 771 676381375.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
```

Please any advice on how to get rid of this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/

Comment: Maybe you can define what exactly you mean by "rsync technique"? If you just copied the files from a running server, your copy is invalid.

Comment: I meant using rsync to copy the datadir to the other server. Thanks.